# Xamarin forms Memory issue

Tags: xamarin, memory-leaks, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I want to optimize my Xamarin.Forms app, so I am starting to use Xamarin Profiler, and I can see that the initial memory allocated in my Android app is always around 50MB.

The allocated memory is 50MB when the app starts, and it starts to increase around +1.6MB when I do push and around +0.2MB when I pull a page.

Of course, the more I navigate, the app goes slower and slower.

But I don't know if this amount is OK or if the app is consuming too much memory.

Guys, could you orient me a bit more about this? I am using MVVMCross (as MVVM framework) and I am not showing images in the MainPage.

Comment: Have you tried going through [this] (https://xamarinhelp.com/tracking-memory-leaks-xamarin-profiler/) article helps you a lot. But as Yaser's answer suggested if they app is slowing down and memory keeps on increasing with time and usage then you have a leak.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of open source xamarin forms projects on GitHub, try profiling them and compare them with your app.

But, if app goes slower and slower when you navigate between forms, and you see more memory usage, you're suffering from memory leak.